# Java - setting classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

My sample application tells me:

```
No 'qtjambi-deployment.xml' found in classpath, loading
libraries via 'java.library.path'
```

I wish for my application to use the `qtjambi-deployment.xml`, but unfortunately can't find the appropriate setting in `IntelliJ IDEA 10.5`.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can right click on any directory in your IntelliJ project, select "Mark Directory As...", and choose "Source Root".  That director folder will change color from yellow to blue; IntelliJ considers all those directories to be in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Will those settings remain in effect for ALL future projects?

Comment: No, local to the current project.  They are all independent.  If you use Maven and its standard directory structure IntelliJ will be smart enough to follow conventions.

Comment: I need to add a jar file that has specialized testing...stuff. If I go to project structure, would the jar be considered a library?

Comment: Yes.  Non-Maven you'd add it to a /lib folder and add that to CLASSPATH.  If you're using Maven you'd include that in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 3):

- From the top menu click 'Run' => 'Edit Configurations'
- Choose the right 'Application' in the left column (if it's not yet selected)
- Click on 'Configuration' tab in the right hand side column (if it's not yet selected)
- Click the '...' button to the right of 'Environment variables:'
- Click the '+' button.

Comment: The environment variable being asked is CLASSPATH

Comment: Doesn't work for me. How's it gonna work anyway when the `-classpath` is going to **replace** your `CLASSPATH` variable? https://archive.is/f9GRk#selection-527.13-533.4

Answer (score 0):

`qtjambi-deployment.xml` file is situated in `qtjambi-win<architecture>-msvc<year>-<vertion>.jar`. Add this package to your classpath and your building problem will be solved. I hope)