# ical4j.properties file IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ical4j

I've been trying to parse an iCal file using `ical4j` but I can't seem to make it find the `ical4j.properties` file.

From the [documentation](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Compatibility) we can read that we should create a file within our classpath. So according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104551/java-setting-classpath) I should have done exactly that. My directory structure looks as follows:

```
src
-- main/
----java/
------project/
------ical4j.properties
------main.java
----resource/
--test/
```

The folder named `Java` is indeed blue so it should be in my classpath. It also contains the properties file so I'm stuck on how to get it to find the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place the `ical4j.properties` in your resources folder and it will work

Comment: Derp, why did I not try that. Thank you :)