# babelfy.properties is missing in Java

Tags: java, named-entity-recognition, word-sense-disambiguation

I am trying to disambiguate a list of words using BabelFy. I started with the example provided in API page of Babelfy. but I got the Error about the "key" that I got from Babelfy.
I already filled the file with the key. but it says it it empty.

```
Nov 02, 2017 4:23:03 PM it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.commons.BabelfyConfiguration <init>
INFO: babelfy.properties is missing. Please check that the file is available 
in the config folder.
Nov 02, 2017 4:23:03 PM it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.commons.BabelfyConfiguration 
<init>
INFO: Babelfy starts with empty configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please define 
the parameter babelfy.key in babelfy.properties in the config folder.
```

here is my code:

```
public class WSDBabelfy {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        String inputText = "BabelNet is both a multilingual encyclopedic dictionary and a semantic network";
        BabelfyConstraints constraints = new BabelfyConstraints();
        SemanticAnnotation a = new SemanticAnnotation(new TokenOffsetFragment(0, 0), "<the key>",
                "http://dbpedia.org/resource/BabelNet", SemanticAnnotation.Source.OTHER);

        constraints.addAnnotatedFragments(a);
        BabelfyParameters bp = new BabelfyParameters();
        bp.setAnnotationResource(BabelfyParameters.SemanticAnnotationResource.BN);
        bp.setMCS(BabelfyParameters.MCS.ON_WITH_STOPWORDS);
        bp.setScoredCandidates(BabelfyParameters.ScoredCandidates.ALL);
        Babelfy bfy = new Babelfy(bp);
        List<SemanticAnnotation> bfyAnnotations = bfy.babelfy(inputText, Language.EN, constraints);
    //bfyAnnotations is the result of Babelfy.babelfy() call
        for (SemanticAnnotation annotation : bfyAnnotations)
        {
            //splitting the input text using the CharOffsetFragment start and end anchors
            String frag = inputText.substring(annotation.getCharOffsetFragment().getStart(),
                    annotation.getCharOffsetFragment().getEnd() + 1);
            System.out.println(frag + "\t" + annotation.getBabelSynsetID());
            System.out.println("\t" + annotation.getBabelNetURL());
            System.out.println("\t" + annotation.getDBpediaURL());
            System.out.println("\t" + annotation.getSource());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is properties file

```
babelfy.key=<the key>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did experience the same issue, is the `config` folder well at the root of the project? Also, do you include it in the `classpath` as in the example below (or in your IDE)?

`java -classpath lib/*:babelfy-online-1.0.jar:config it.uniroma1.lcl.babelfy.demo.BabelfyDemo`

Comment: I usually use this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104551/java-setting-classpath" to make everything in classpath. 
but I do not know where I should write in Classaeth.

could you please give a hint.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, like IntelliJ IDEA? Beside this, running the line I indicated above includes all that is needed in the classpath: (1) all `.jar` file in `lib/`; (2) the `babelfy-online-1.0.jar` supposedly placed at the root of the project; (3) the `config/` folder with the 2 property files.